# How to update the screenshot of an app on IOS 7

Tags: ios7

I was reading a very interesting [article](http://engineering.pinterest.com/post/67769846580/behind-the-pins-building-pinterest-3-0-for-ios) about the Pinterest app updated for IOS 7. One of the new things added was the possibility to see in the screenshot of the app if there are any new updates:

Since iOS7 also allows you to update the screenshot for your app in the multitasking view, this was a great opportunity to grab the user’s attention to open up the app.

[image]

How can you achieve this IOS 7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved via the new iOS 7 Background refresh modes.

It all comes down to the `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` method on the `UIApplicationDelegate` ([more info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aperformFetchWithCompletionHandler%3a))

It's worth checking out the "What's New with Multitasking" video from the 2013 WWDC sessions https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

It will walk you through all the relevant steps to achieve what you have described